# Argument of type 'typeof session' is not assignable to parameter of type '(options?: SessionOptions | undefined) => .. Ben Awad full stack tutorial

Tags: typescript, redis

I am currently trying to connect Redis to my application, here is the index.ts below

```
import "reflect-metadata";
import { MikroORM } from "@mikro-orm/core";
import { __prod__ } from "./constants";
import microConfig from "./mikro-orm.config";
import express from "express";
import redis from "redis";
import session from "express-session";
import connectRedis from "connect-redis";


const main = async () => {
  const orm = await MikroORM.init(microConfig);
  await orm.getMigrator().up();

  const app = express();

  const RedisStore = connectRedis(session);
  const redisClient = redis.createClient();

  app.use(
    session({
      name: "qid",
      store: new RedisStore({ client: redisClient, disableTouch: true }),
      cookie: {
        maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365 * 10, //10 years
        httpOnly: true,
        sameSite: "lax",
        secure: __prod__
      },
      saveUninitialized: false,
      secret: "qweqweqweqweqweqwe",
      resave: false
    })
  );


  app.listen(4000, () => {
    console.log("running on port 4000");
  });
};

main().catch((err) => {
  console.error(err);
});
```

but on the line `const RedisStore = connectRedis(session);` , specifically session, has the following error.

```
Argument of type 'typeof session' is not assignable to parameter of type '(options?: SessionOptions | undefined) => RequestHandler<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs, Record<string, any>>'.
  Types of parameters 'options' and 'options' are incompatible.
    Type 'import("/Users/rohansingh/Dropbox/Mac/Desktop/big_project/node_modules/@types/connect-redis/node_modules/@types/express-session/index").SessionOptions | undefined' is not assignable to type 'import("/Users/rohansingh/Dropbox/Mac/Desktop/big_project/node_modules/@types/express-session/index").SessionOptions | undefined'.
```

I made sure the my code matched Ben Awad's, but I still have this error

[Here is the picture of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rxpE2.jpg)

Thank you in advanced

Comment: pls provide minimum reproducable example

Comment: Did you ever solve this, I'm having the same problem with his tutorial

Comment: No, I gave up. I will try the tutorial again with fresh eyes, and see if I can find the solution.